# Find the singularity and its order

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z),g(z),r(z),h(z)$ be analytic functions near $z_0$.
>
> Where at $z_0$:
>
> 1. f(z) is a pole of order $2$
> 2. g(z) has a zero of order $3$
> 3. r(z) has a zero of order $2$
> 4. h(z) has a zero of order $1$
>
> Find the singularity and its order$$\frac{f(z)+g(z)}{r(z)+h(z)}$$

$$\frac{f(z)+g(z)}{r(z)+h(z)}=\frac{\frac{\tilde{f(z)}}{(z-z_0)^3}+(z-z_0)^3\tilde{g(z)}}{(z-z_0)^2\tilde{r(z)}+(z-z_0)\tilde{h(z)}}=\frac{\frac{\tilde{f(z)}+(z-z_0)^5\tilde{g(z)}}{(z-z_0)^2}}{(z-z_0)[\tilde{r(z)}(z-z_0)+\tilde{h(z)}]}=\frac{{\tilde{f(z)}+(z-z_0)^5\tilde{g(z)}}}{(z-z_0)^3[\tilde{r(z)}(z-z_0)+\tilde{h(z)}]}$$

How should I continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this help.

$=\frac{F(z)}{(z-z_0)^3}$, where $F(z)=\frac{\bar f(z)+(z-z_0)^5\bar g(z)}{(z-z_0)\bar r(z)+\bar h(z)}$ has no singularity at $z_0$.

So, $z_0$ is a pole of order 3.